# Find number of files deleted

Tags: countif

I want to know how many files deleted thru batch script. I found a script and modified it but it does not work. Any idea how to fix it.

```
set-location d:\testing -ErrorAction stop               # Change directory
$files = get-childitem -File                                   # Get all 
the files in this directory
$folders = get-childitem -directory                            # Get all 
the folders in this directory

$count = ($files|measure).count                                # 
($files|measure).count gives how 
                                                           # many files 
are in this collection.
$countfo = ($folders|measure).count                            # 
($files|measure).count gives how 
                                                           # many files 
are in this collection.

Start-Sleep -s 5

write-host "There are $($count) files to be deleted."          # Write 
that to the screen.
$files | remove-item                                           # remove 
the files

write-host "There are $($countfo) folders to be deleted."      # Write 
that to the screen.
$folders | remove-item                                         # remove 
the files

$files = get-childitem -File                                   # Get all 
the files in this directory
                                                           # after the 
delete to find out how
                                                           # how many 
remained.

$folders = get-childitem -directory                              # Get all 
the folders in this directory
                                                           # after the 
delete to find out how
                                                           # how many 
remained.


$count2 = ($files|measure).count                               # 
$countfinal = $count-$count2

$countfo2 = ($folders|measure).count
$countfofinal = $countfo-$countfo2

write-host "$($count2) files remained. " -NoNewline            # 
write-host "$($countfinal) files were deleted. "               # 

write-host "$($countfo2) folders remained. " -NoNewline        # 
write-host "$($countfofinal) folders were deleted. "           # 

Start-Sleep -s 5
```

[image: Prompt]

Comment: Is a batchfile required? This works so much easier in Powershell. You can then first make a collection in your search, count it, and then delete it.

Comment: Hi, Powershell is fine if it can do both jobs - delete files and count the deleted files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to delete all files in the folder specified at the top of the script. The -erroraction stop is there in case the folder does not exist, the script aborts rather than to delete all files in the current folder.

```
set-location d:\testing -ErrorAction stop               # Change directory
$files = get-childitem -File                            # Get all the files in this directory

$count = ($files|measure).count                         # ($files|measure).count gives how 
                                                        # many files are in this collection.
write-host "There are $($count) files to be deleted."   # Write that to the screen.
$files | remove-item                                    #remove the files

$files = get-childitem -File                            # Get all the files in this directory
                                                        # after the delete to find out how
                                                        # how many remained.
$count2 = ($files|measure).count                        # 
$countfinal = $count-$count2
write-host "$($count2) files remained. " -NoNewline     # 
write-host "$($countfinal) files were delted. "         #
```

Comment: Hi, this may work  in normal directory. However there are some files which deny to delete in windows/temp directory, the count of deleted files is not accurate ! Any workaround ?

Comment: I've updated the script. It now counts before and after to tell you how many files were there before, after and how many files were deleted.